# Как перейти по ссылке из "Страницы 1" на нужный абзац "Страницы 2"?

Tags: c#, winforms

Планирую сделать систему управления контентом.
Состав системы:
   - Страницы по категориям. (Pages by Category);
   - Текстовый редактор. (Text editor);

Текст страниц содержит форматированный текст, картинки.
Текст в формате HTML хранится в базе данных.
Дерево категорий выводит текст из базы данных в текстовый редактор.

**Логика**
    1. В "PagesByCategory" находится дерево страниц;
    2. Каждая страница состоит из строк;
        Страница 1:
            - Строка 1 Страница 1;
            - Строка 2 Страница 1;
            - Строка 3 Страница 1.
        Страница 2:
            - Строка 1 Страница 2;
            - Строка 2 Страница 2;
            - Строка 3 Страница 2.
    3. Выбираю страницу в дереве (Например: "Страница 1");
    4. Страница отображается в "TextEditor";
    5. Читаю страницу в "TextEditor";
    6. На странице "Страница 1" вижу ссылку на "Строка 2 Страница 2";
    7. Нажимаю ссылку.
    8. В "TextEditor" открывается "Страница 2", скролл останавливается на "Строка 2".

**Вопросы**
    1. Как сделать чтобы пользователь смог создавать ссылки на "фрагменты текста" на других страницах?
       Т. е. создать на странице "Страница 1" ссылки на "Страницу 2" "фрагмент текста".

Пример
    "Страница 1":
            - Строка 1 Страница 1;
            -- *Ссылка - Строка **2** Страница 2;*
            - Строка 2 Страница 1;
            -- *Ссылка - Строка **3** Страница 2;*
            - Строка 3 Страница 1.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Наверно можно пойти разными путями. Например можно просто по нажатию на строчку в категории 2 на странице "PagesByCategory", заранее по  заданному соответствию(Текст который вы ищите, к строке из категории 2)перемещать каретку в "TextEditor" на нужный текст.

Comment: @YuryBakharev Я дополнил вопрос. Ваш комментарий подразумевает, ту логику. которую я описал? Может мне вообще стоит подругому организовать систему? Например размещать контент не в базе, а в файлах PS Я плохо разбираюсь в этих вопросах

Comment: В 8 пункте, почему должна открыться 1 страница, если ссылка на стр 2?

Comment: @Yury Bakharev Исправил

Comment: @Yury Bakharev Дополнил вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать объект linkLabel. Добавьте его на первый текст бокс!

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.linkLabel1.LinkClicked += LinkLabel1_LinkClicked;
        this.linkLabel1.Text = "Нужный вам текст на странице 2";
    }

    private void LinkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        int index =  richTextBox2.Text.IndexOf("Нужный вам текст на странице 2");
        richTextBox2.Select(0, index);
        richTextBox2.SelectionStart = richTextBox2.SelectionLength;
        richTextBox2.SelectionLength = "Нужный вам текст на странице 2".Length ;
        richTextBox2.Focus();
    }
}
```

После этого вы сможете увидеть в фокусе текст "Нужный вам текст на странице 2", если он там конечно есть.

Comment: Может вам нетрудно посоветовать ссылку или пример как "linkLabel" разместить в "richTextBox"? Я пока ищу, но что-то как-то сложновато. Может есть более простые пути. Разбираюсь

Comment: @climivin перетянуть на форму из панели элементов

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Пока изучаю этот вопрос. Изменил вопрос: `1. Как сделать чтобы пользователь смог создавать ссылки на "фрагменты текста" на других страницах?`

Comment: программно добавляйте linklabel. Сделайте ui для создания таких ссылок, там и заполняйте все необходимые параметры(текст, название ссылки и т д)